# How can I randomize a set of variables with a probability attached to each outcome?

Tags: excel

This is a somewhat abstract problem:

I have a list of 5,000,000 people who live in a city.
The list is made of a few lists of prevalence (in percent) of certain traits: first name, last name, gender, age, etc.

I wish to randomly create a person with one trait from each list with the random generation accurately representing the probability of that person. For example, Robert Smith, age 25, is far more common than Herbert Wellington, age 120, so I'll make more Robert Smiths than Herbert Wellingtons.

Let's say I don't need to keep track of each individual, so rolling a Robert Smith doesn't diminish the probability of the next individual being a Robert or a Smith.

Ideally, this would be one function: rolling the die determines every trait all at once.

Walk me through the logic of how this problem can be solved, preferably in something simple enough that I can build it in excel or batch (because I am not experienced in anything else).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?  Do you have the LET function?

Comment: Where is your "list of 5,000,000 people" stored?  Cleary not in a sheet...

Comment: Can you give us an idea of how many items are on each list (number of first names, number of last names...) and how many items you want to generate plz? I think I could suggest a scenario with a smallish number, but it might not scale.

Comment: Sample data would really really help us help you.  It doesn't seem like a particularly difficult problem, but there's not enough here to get started roughing out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this topic would involve using trunc(10000*rand()) to generate a random number between 1 and 10000. For each trait, I would create a table with the number of people out of ten thousand who would have that trait or the traits above it. Then you could use a vlookup with an approximate match to give you the trait that corresponds to that random number. Repeat this process for all of your traits and you’ve generated a randomized person based on the frequency of traits.

Using trunc with rand to create a random integer:
https://magoosh.com/excel/using-the-random-function-in-excel/

A similar example of the vlookup table:
https://exceljet.net/formula/calculate-grades-with-vlookup